# Why did I get the error cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name' in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables

I am trying to declare new variable called name in my typescript code. I have only one line of code.

```
var name:string = "John";
```

But got error

```
PS D:\TypeScript> tsc test.ts
C:/Users/Users/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(18568,15): error TS2451: Cannot re
declare block-scoped variable 'name'.
test.ts(1,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.
```

What is the reason behind this error?

[image: cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name']

[image: cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name']

Comment: The error arises because the variable `name` already exists on the global scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, TypeScript uses the DOM typings for the global execution environment and there is a name property on the global window in the DOM

If you change your var name to name1, it wont show you this error. However, typescript recommends ES6 syntax, so your IDE may suggests you to use const/let instead.

Take a look at this link 
    https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22436

Hope this helps.

Happy Learning

Comment: A workaround would be to define it as such: `export var name: string = "John";`

Answer (score 8):

To get around this, you can simply have an export statement that exports nothing. In other words, just write

```
 export {};
```

somewhere at the top-level of your file.